# Coding A Simple Website Example in HTML

Tags: css, html, colors

I am just beginning to learn HTML and I need help with making an example I found. Here is an image ([link](http://prntscr.com/5411yd)):

[image]

I know how to make the black background but I have no clue how to add the body in the middle of the page! Extra Information that was provided to me:

Color Code: #fe9;
Font: "Palatino",serif;
Width is 400px;

If anyone could help out even the littlest bit I would appreciate it! It also uses the embedded style!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a div inside your body tag. And then apply css to that div.
Say give it margin: 0 auto;

Answer (score 0):

You need a containing element, usually a div.  All your content should be inside this div.  Then you can style the div to be a set width and centered, and give the div a background, etc.

Example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style>
#container {
  width: 400px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: #fe9;
  font-family: "Palatino",serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
My Content
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You should be able to figure out the rest of the content; if you can't, please ask specific questions about what you need to do and give details about what you have already tried.

Comment: Basically I know how to make the page black but have no idea how to add the yellow part inside it and the big break between the text at top and at the bottom! Thanks for your reply!

Comment: well, first you have to set up the container div as outlined.  the background of the container should be the yellow - #fe9 is a yellow.  
After you've done that, because you've already been given that answer, what have you tried for the text?

Comment: If another answer doesn't come along in the meantime, I'll come back to this and walk you through it step by step.  But you need to at least try it on your own first.

Comment: Thanks you! I will try it myself for a while now and post back.

Comment: I'm not able to do it at all, the spacing is not working, padding, margins all that doesn't work :/ This is what I've done so far: http://www.mediafire.com/view/gnluy58w4huuf99/Meridien.html